# What is the maximum number of datanodes in Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using 8 node hadoop cluster and namenode memory usage shows as 7%. I feel this cluster going to reach maximum limits of namenode memory.

Current cluster storage size is 5.6TB and namenode heap size is 4GB. Further block size is 128MB.

**What is the way of calculating maximum number of datanodes that can have for Hadoop cluster (with single namenode)?**

Answer (score 2):

Namenode memory usage is proportional to the number of blocks also the guideline is 1 million blocks take 1 GB memory...and with you 5.6 TB and 128 MB block size i calculated you can have around half million blocks without even replication(you can recalculate). So, my conclusion is you have enough memory unless there are lots of small files...